# Do TortoiseGit and other shell extensions try to process remote fle systems?

Tags: windows-7, shell-extensions, tortoise-git

Some of Windows directories mapped to WAN links and sometimes when I am browsing with Windows explorer it takes ages to respond. I am beginning to suspect that some of the shell extensions are scanning the remote file systems and this is causing explorer to hang.

Is there some way to configure a shell extension not to scan specified directories, especially TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to TortoiseGit settings to the page "Icon Overlays". There you can configure which type of paths should be scanned in general or you can restrict the scanning to entered paths.

See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-overlay

Comment: It is something I have noticed and tried, but I probably have to reboot or restart Tortoise to see if it works well enough